Amazon S3 access point policy
I'm trying to create a policy in the amazon s3 access point to deny everything except if the object tag is odd, but I get an error.
So far it looks like this:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::326271689035:instance-profile/acessa-s3"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:us-east-1:326271689035:accesspoint/pontodeacessolab/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:ExistingObjectTag/conjunto": "impar"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

I tried using Amazon Q but was unsuccessful.

What is the error message? I suspect the problem is because you are are attempting to use a Condition on every S3 command (s3:*). However, not every S3 API call supports this capability. For example, creating a bucket does not accept object tags since it does not process objects. Please review Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon S3 - Service Authorization Reference, which lists which Actions accept the s3:ExistingObjectTag/<key> condition.
